# two fragments hold by single action bar tab Android

Tags: android, fragment

I would like to show 2 different fragments inside a single Tab in android action bar tab.

What I would do is something like:

```
public class Frag1 extends Fragment { 

   @Override
   public void onCreateOptionsMenu (Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {

    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.frag1_menu, menu);
    }

    @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {

    case R.id.item1:
               break;
            case R.id.item_GoToFrag2:
                    FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction(); 
        ft.remove(Frag1.this); 

                    Fragment mFragment = Fragment.instantiate(getActivity(), Frag2.class.getName(), null);             
        ft.add(android.R.id.content, mFragment, Frag2.class.getName() ); 
        ft.commit();
               break;
            } 
    return true;
}
}
```

the code for Frag2 is exactly the same, the unique difference is in the onOptionsItemSelected where there is a case like:

```
            case R.id.item_GoToFrag1:
                    FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction(); 
        ft.remove(Frag2.this); 

                    Fragment mFragment = Fragment.instantiate(getActivity(), Frag2.class.getName(), null);             
        ft.add(android.R.id.content, mFragment, Frag1.class.getName() ); 
        ft.commit();
               break;
```

Everything SEEMS to work fine, the problem is that when I switch to a different tab, the icons related to the Frag2 are still visible to all other tabs and I really don't understand why, I also call the  getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu(); but with no success.... can anyone help me?

Comment: Just a side note. Are you sure that you want to be using Fragments as opposed to creating a custom View?

Answer (score 0):

If you are simply trying replace a fragment, then call [ft.replace](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#replace%28int,%20android.app.Fragment,%20java.lang.String%29)

Also, why would do this?

```
Fragment mFragment = Fragment.instantiate(getActivity(), Frag2.class.getName(), null);             
        ft.add(android.R.id.content, mFragment, Frag1.class.getName() );
```

You're adding the Frag2 and then tagging it as Frag1 in the ft.add

Comment: even if I fix the tagging error, the problem persists... the point is that even if the fragment is replaced, the related ICONS on the actionbar are not refreshed even if I call the  invalidateOptionsMenu()...

Answer (score 0):

Dont add the fragments in XML file. Just create containers and put the fragments programmatically.